Request the user's phone number directly through the Telegram WebApp
I want to request the user's phone number directly through the Telegram WebApp.
I created this code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Telegram WebView</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>User Details</h1>
    <button id="getUserDetails">Get User Details</button>
    <div id="userDetails"></div>
    <button id="requestPhone">Request Phone Number</button>

    <script src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web-app.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('getUserDetails').addEventListener('click', function() {
            const user = Telegram.WebApp.initDataUnsafe.user;

            if (user) {
                const userDetails = `
                    <p>Full Name: ${user.first_name} ${user.last_name || ''}</p>
                    <p>Username: ${user.username || 'N/A'}</p>
                    <p>User ID: ${user.id}</p>
                `;
                document.getElementById('userDetails').innerHTML = userDetails;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('userDetails').innerHTML = '<p>Unable to fetch user details.</p>';
            }
        });

        document.getElementById('requestPhone').addEventListener('click', function() {
            Telegram.WebApp.requestPhone();
        });

        Telegram.WebApp.onEvent('phone_requested', function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'success' && response.phone_number) {
                const phoneDetails = `<p>Phone Number: ${response.phone_number}</p>`;
                document.getElementById('userDetails').innerHTML += phoneDetails;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('userDetails').innerHTML += '<p>Failed to get phone number.</p>';
            }
        });

        // Initialize the Telegram WebApp
        Telegram.WebApp.ready();
    </script>
</body>
</html>


But here I have an error:

url.php:32 Uncaught TypeError: Telegram.WebApp.requestPhone is not a
function. read this:
https://core.telegram.org/api/web-events#web-app-request-phone

So "Get User Details" is working fully but "Request Phone Number" is not working. I am not able to find the error. Please help me to solve this.

The line Telegram.WebApp.requestPhone() is causing the error since you try to call the method (i. e. function) requestPhone() which does not exist. Either it is really non-existing, or it is something differnt to a function - that's why the error message says " ... is not a function".
